# How to use the Big-Sur style toolbar + split view from an old codebase?

Tags: macos, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

According to [this WWDC 2020 talk](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10104),
Big Sur's toolbar is automatically sectioned to match and follow the panes of the `NSSplitView` below.

Unfortunately, this requires us to use the post-`NSViewController` version of `NSSplitView` api, introduced in 10.10 Yosemite (see the corresponding [WWDC 2014 session PDF](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/212xxi1kzzkdr54/212/212_storyboards_and_controllers_on_os_x.pdf?dl=1) here.)

What would be the easiest way to use it from a really old codebase with pre-`NSViewController` `NSSplitView` in XIB?

The new-style `NSSplitView` is famously unavailable in XIB and only available in the storyboard, as discussed in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870957/nssplitviewcontroller-nssplitviewitem-support-in-xibs).

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can swap the `NSSplitView` from the old-style one to the new-style one inside `awakeFromNib`. A sample code follows.

I assumed `window` and `oldSplitView` are `IBOutlet` to corresponding objects within XIB, and two dummy `NSViewController`s `leftVC` and `rightVC` are created within XIB whose `view`s are connected to the left pane and right pane. Then all you have to do is:

```
    // enable scrolling behind the tool bar, if you haven't
    window.styleMask|=NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView;

    // create a new-style NSSplitView using NSSplitViewController
    splitVC=[[NSSplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitVC.splitView.vertical=YES;
    splitVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

    // prepare the left pane as a sidebar
    NSSplitViewItem*a=[NSSplitViewItem sidebarWithViewController:leftVC];
    [splitVC addSplitViewItem:a];
    a.canCollapse=NO;

    // prepare the right pane
    NSSplitViewItem*b=[NSSplitViewItem splitViewItemWithViewController:rightVC];
    [splitVC addSplitViewItem:b];

    // swap the old NSSplitView with the new one
    [window.contentView replaceSubview:oldSplitView with:splitVC.view ];

    // set up the constraints so that the new `NSSplitView` to fill the window
    [splitVC.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:window.contentView.topAnchor
                                           constant:0].active=YES;
    [splitVC.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:((NSLayoutGuide*)window.contentLayoutGuide).bottomAnchor].active=YES;
    [splitVC.view.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:((NSLayoutGuide*)window.contentLayoutGuide).leftAnchor].active=YES;
    [splitVC.view.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:((NSLayoutGuide*)window.contentLayoutGuide).rightAnchor].active=YES;
```